# I would like to cache images in react, what should I use for storage

Tags: reactjs, image, caching

I would like to cache image in react.

`<img src='www.myimage/dog.png' />`

Every time I load page, `dog.png` is downloaded from page. I would like to store it in browser with some `ttl`.

Should I use `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, `indexedDb` or what is the best place to store and why?

Thank you!

Comment: the browser already caches images for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to cache your images yourself. Unless you're doing some specialised lazy-loading, the browser will automatically cache it for you.

They will still "load", but from cache. And they may be at the browser's discretion.

To confirm, open dev tools > network > Img and see how the images are loaded from cache, instead of an endpoint.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful.